# Porque me imprime caracteres basura?

Tags: c

Tengo problemas al imprimir lo que introduzco ya que siempre me devuelve caracteres basura.

El código consiste crear una lista doblemente enlazada, donde se pueda ingresar, buscar y eliminar elementos. Pero el problema radica en que cuando quiero imprimir lo que introduje solo me muestra caracteres basura.

Cabe mencionar que no he practicado mucho listas por lo que puede que sea un error pequeño o que la mitad del código esté mal.

El código lo hice basándome en otros ejercicios que he hecho pero de listas simples.Dejo el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

typedef struct datos{
char clases[30];
struct datos *sig;
struct datos *ant;
}doble;

doble *nuevo_nodo();
int InsertarInicio(doble **cab, char clases[]);
int InsertarFinal(doble **cab, char clases[]);
void ImprimirLista(doble *cab);
int EliminarNodo(doble **cab, char clases[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

char clases[30];

doble *cab=NULL;
printf("Ingrese una clase: ");
scanf("%s",clases);
InsertarInicio(&cab,clases);
InsertarFinal(&cab,"hola");
ImprimirLista(cab);

return 0;
}

int InsertarFinal(doble **cab, char clases[])
{
doble *nuevo = NULL, *aux = *cab;

nuevo = nuevo_nodo(clases);
if (nuevo != NULL)
{
    while(aux->sig != NULL){ aux = aux->sig;}
    nuevo->ant = aux;
    aux->sig = nuevo;
    return 1;
}
return 0;
}

void ImprimirLista(doble *cab)
{
doble *aux = cab;
fflush(stdin);
while(aux != NULL)
{
    printf("\n%s", aux->clases);
    aux = aux->sig;
}

}

int InsertarInicio(doble **cab, char clases[])
{
doble *nuevo = NULL;

nuevo = nuevo_nodo(clases);
if (nuevo!=NULL)
{
    nuevo->sig = *cab;
    nuevo->ant = NULL;
    if( *cab != NULL)
    (*cab)->ant = nuevo;
    *cab = nuevo;
    return 1;
}
return 0;
}

doble *nuevo_nodo()
{
doble* nuevo = NULL;

nuevo = (doble*)malloc(sizeof(doble));
return nuevo;
}
```

Comment: Cuando llamas a `nuevo_nodo()` le pasas un parámetro. Sin embargo la implementación de esa función no declara parámetros. Entiendo que ese parámetro es lo que deberías asignar al campo `clase` del nodo, el cual por lo que se ve queda sin asignar, de modo que no me extraña que luego, cuando imprimes ese campo como cadena, sólo obtengas basura, puesto que es un puntero que apunta a un lugar al azar en la memoria. No sería extraño tampoco que el programa "rompiera" con un segfault si el puntero apuntara a una zona protegida.

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero que llama la atención es esta llamada:

```
int InsertarFinal(doble **cab, char clases[])
{
    doble *nuevo = NULL, *aux = *cab;

    nuevo = nuevo_nodo(clases); // <<--- ESTA
```

Ya que si atendemos a la declaración de la función vemos que **no tiene argumentos**:

```
doble *nuevo_nodo();
```

Bueno, realmente no quiere decir eso, ya que de ser así habrías obtenido un error en tiempo de compilación. En C cuando no se dejan vacíos los paréntesis significa que la función puede recibir un número arbitrario de parámetros... no es tu caso ya que creo que a ti te gustaría que el nodo tuviese inicialmente la cadena que acaba de introducir el usuario.

La declaración debería quedar así:

```
doble *nuevo_nodo(char * const cadena);
```

y la implementación:

```
doble *nuevo_nodo(char * const cadena)
{
  doble* nuevo = (doble*)calloc(1, sizeof(doble));
  strcpy(nuevo->clases, cadena);
  return nuevo;
}
```

Pero claro, resulta que la estructura `doble` tiene 3 variables, de las cuales dos son punteros `ant` y `sig`... ¿A donde apuntan? A cualquier parte!!!

Para evitar sustos conviene incializar dichos punteros. Puedes optar por hacerlo a mano:

```
nuevo = (doble*)malloc(sizeof(doble));
nuevo->sig = NULL;
nuevo->ant = NULL;
```

O puedes usar `calloc` en vez de `malloc`, de esta forma **todos los bytes** de la reserva se inicializan a 0 y asunto resuelto:

```
nuevo = (doble*)calloc(1, sizeof(doble));
```

El programa sería mejorable en otros aspectos pero con estos cambios ya cumple con su objetivo